# The best aproach to translate a page in a web app

Tags: translation

I'm developing a web application using Spring, JSF 2 and Primefaces 3. I want the user to be able to choose from different languages. I don't want to use Google Translate. Which is the best approach to translate my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/#Properties

Basically, you create a properties file for each language, like messages.properties, messages_fr.properties, messages_es.properties etc. and the appropriate one is loaded according to the locale.

The user can also select the language herself, take a look at the next tutorials at that site to see how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to implement this technically or how to get the content of your site translated?

For the former I trust you can [find a guide or five](http://www.google.com/search?q=spring+jsf+i18n).

For the latter if you don't want to use an automated service like Google Translate then you're going to need humans to do it for you. Unless you have multilingual friends who owe you a favor or, say, a giant, enthusiastic userbase like Facebook or Twitter has, you're not going to get this for free. Your options, basically, are to pay for the services of one of the many, many companies out there that do this, or find multilingual individuals on your own, e.g. by calling local universities' foreign language departments or international student organizations, or posting on Craigslist and the like. As with web development contractors, I think it's safe to assume you get what you pay for.

Comment: I'm asking which is the best way to implement it technically. I only need 3 languages and I believe I can manage on my own!

Comment: See the link in the second sentence of my answer. Lots of documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you don't want to use Google Translate, do you men GT specifically, or any such service? Because if you're not using any translation service, you'll have to maintain versions of each page on your site in different languages. And maintain them.

Come to think of it, you probably have to take this approach as none of the online translation services provide a good enough native translation.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some commercial machine-translation packages out there, but they don't come cheap, I imagine.

Alternatively, employ an army of translators - there's websites out there where you can hire translators.

You'll probably want to do a search for translation software, then figure out how much it'd cost you.